# Why is the loop altering the if else stmt. after completing every second for loop and displays the same values as those were set in the beginning

Tags: python-3.4

matrix = 10 * [10 * [0]]

print("Before")

for x in range(10):

```
    for y in range(10):

        print(matrix[x][y])
```

for x in range(10):

```
    for y in range(10):
        print("X, Y", x, y)
        if matrix[x][y]== 0:
            print("Inside If")
            print("Before Changing", matrix[x][y])
            matrix[x][y] = 1
            print("After Changing", matrix[x][y])
        else:
            print("Inside Else")
            print("Before Changing", matrix[x][y])
            matrix[x][y] = 0
            print("After Changing", matrix[x][y])
    print("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

print("After")

for x in range(10):

```
    for y in range(10):
        print(matrix[x][y])
```

Comment: Please edit your question, because it is completely unclear what is your problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

the declaration of matrix causes the object to copy the sublist 10 times. That means, matrix is a list of 10 copies of a list of 10 zeroes.

Each iteration over x will set the values of all lists. Each iteration over y addresses the same value, but in different copies.

For sake of clarity, assume matrix=2*[2*[0]]
This looks like matrix=[[0,0],[0,0]]
If you set matrix[0][1]=1, it will set not only the second value of the first sublist, but also (because it is a copy) the second value of the second list:
matrix=[[0,1],[0,1]]

Because your iteration over y is an even number, it will set values to 1 first, then set them to 0 back. If y were uneven, you would end up with only 1's everywhere.

I think what you wanted is 
matrix = [10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0],10*[0]]

This will end up with a matrix filled with 1's